# Include .resx language file to installer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, resources, installshield

I have a WPF project with three Res.x.resx files of strings, where x is it, en and de (Italian, English and German respectively). These files are in a Resource folder in which there are also some bitmap files; all these resources are setted as 'embedded resources'. When I create an installer with InstallShield, Res.x.resx files are not included because I receive the following error:

"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "wpfApp.Resources.Res.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "wpfApp" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

I've seen many tutorial but I haven't resolved my problem. Could someone help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.resources` files are the binary compiled ones. If you want to include the source `.resx` files add them as any other file.

Comment: I've already added them as text file in Resources.resx but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I've finally solved my problem directly in InstallShield Application Files interface. I've added a localized resources in the same folder of the primary output and now it works. I hope this can help someone that have the same problem.